# Command found with `which` at the new paths but still tries to run from the old path

Tags: terminal, command-line, path, environment-variables

I have installed new version of `npm` in the custom directory `.npm-global/bin` and removed it from `/usr/local/bin`. The new path is declared:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:./node_modules/.bin:/Users/dmitrizaitsev/.npm-global/bin:...
```

and the new `npm` is found with `which`:

```
which npm
/Users/dmitrizaitsev/.npm-global/bin/npm
```

However, it still attempts to run from the old path and fails:

```
npm
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old path is still cached by the shell. Either open a new tab/window or run `hash -r` to clear it.